# Is there a way in MySQL to determine every time a record contains a value that is used for the first time?

Tags: mysql, sql, return, unique, distinct

I want to return HTML surrounding the department name every time it is a department name that is returned for the first time. My code right not is is below:

```
SELECT
Company.CompanyID,
Company.Bio,
Company.Email,
People.LastName,
People.FirstName,
Departments.DepartmentName AS DepartmentName,
Departments.DepartmentID
FROM
Company
LEFT JOIN People USING (CompanyID)
LEFT JOIN Departments
ON Departments.DepartmentID = Company.DepartmentID
ORDER BY
Departments.DepartmentID ASC,
People.LastName ASC,
People.FirstName ASC;
```

It returns the below:

```
 +---------+-------------------------------------+-------------+---------+--------+--------+------------+----------+---------+------------+
    |CompanyID| Bio            | Email      |LastName|FirstName|DepartmentName|DepartmentID| 
    +---------+-------------------------------------+-------------+---------+--------+--------+------------+----------+---------+------------+
    | BK001   | Lorem Ipsum ...| e@email.com| Smith | Jay      | Finance     | 1 | 
    | BK002   | Dolor sit am ..| e@email.com| Rhays | Jim      | Marketing   | 2 | 
    | BK003   | Consectetur .. | e@email.com| Carrs | Sam      | IT          | 3 | 
    | BK004   | Sed do eiusm...| e@email.com| Webb  | Bob      | Marketing   | 2 | 
    | BK005   | Concept Phi... | e@email.com| Hart  | Rob      | Design      | 4 |
```

I would like it to return the following:

```
|CompanyID| Bio            | Email      |LastName|FirstName|HTML|DepartmentName|DepartmentID| 
 +---------+-------------------------------------+-------------+---------+--------+--------+------------+----------
| BK001   | Lorem Ipsum ...| e@email.com| Smith | Jay      |<div>|Finance     | 1 | 
| BK002   | Dolor sit am ..| e@email.com| Rhays | Jim      |<div>|Marketing   | 2 | 
| BK003   | Consectetur .. | e@email.com| Carrs | Sam      |<div>|IT          | 3 | 
| BK004   | Sed do eiusm...| e@email.com| Webb  | Bob      |     |Marketing   | 2 | 
| BK005   | Concept Phi... | e@email.com| Hart  | Rob      |<div>|Design      | 4 |
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Case` statement and `Sub-Query`

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN CompanyID = (SELECT Min(C.CompanyID)
                           FROM   Departments D1
                                  JOIN Company C
                                    ON d1.DepartmentID = c.DepartmentID
                           WHERE  D1.DepartmentName = Departments.DepartmentName) THEN '<div>'
         ELSE ''
       END AS HTML,
    ...
FROM ..
```

**Note :** Use `Alias` name to qualify columns instead of writing full table name

Answer (score 0):

One option is to add an additional subquery to select the first occurrence of a department.  I assume that the `CompanyID` represents a chronological order in which a record were inserted into the table, and therefore this is a proxy for what appeared first.

This option might outperform using a subquery in the `SELECT` clause.

```
SELECT t1.CompanyID,
       t1.Bio,
       t1.Email,
       t2.LastName,
       t2.FirstName,
       CASE WHEN t4.DepartmentID IS NOT NULL THEN '<div>' ELSE '' END AS HTML,
       t3.DepartmentName AS DepartmentName,
       t3.DepartmentID
FROM Company t1
LEFT JOIN People t2
    ON t1.CompanyID = t2.CompanyID
LEFT JOIN Departments t3
    ON t3.DepartmentID = t1.DepartmentID
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT d.DepartmentID, MIN(c.CompanyID) AS firstCompanyID    -- this subquery finds
    FROM Company c                                               -- the first appearance of
    LEFT JOIN Departments d                                      -- a company for a given
        ON c.DepartmentID = d.DepartmentID                       -- department
    GROUP BY d.DepartmentID
) t4
    ON t3.DepartmentID = t4.DepartmentID AND
       t1.CompanyID    = t4.firstCompanyID
ORDER BY t3.DepartmentID,
         t2.LastName,
         t2.FirstName;
```

Notes: The reason we can get away with using `MIN` on the `CompanyID` column, which is text, is because the width of all the IDs is fixed as five.  In this case, the lexicographic sorting will be in agreement with the numeric sorting of the digits, which is what we really care about.  Note that this might not work if the width of this field were not fixed.

Comment: DepartmentID is never null. It always returns a value. I need that html column with the sample HTML whenever MySQL is returning 'Marketing' for the first time or 'IT' for the first time

Comment: @sjw0525 Your comment makes no sense to me.  Have you tried my query?

Comment: yes and it returns an HTML column with the sample HTML in it every time DepartmentID is not null, which is every time

Comment: I tried it again. It has the HTML column with the sample html showing up more now but not at the first time each department name returns in the query

Comment: @sjw0525 Then perhaps it is not safe to assume that the minimum `CompanyID` represents the first occurrence.  If you can update your question with actual data having this problem, maybe I can take a look.  Or, better yet, create a Fiddle with your data and add it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Check This.

```
    SET @row_number:=0;
    SET @DepartmentName:='';

    select 
    CompanyID,Bio,Email,LastName,FirstName,
    CASE When row_number ='1' then '<DIV>' else '' end as 'HTML',
    HTML
    DepartmentName,
    DepartmentID
    from
    (
    SELECT
    Company.CompanyID,
    Company.Bio,
    Company.Email,
    People.LastName,
    People.FirstName,
    Departments.DepartmentName AS DepartmentName,
    Departments.DepartmentID ,
    @row_number:=CASE WHEN @DepartmentName=DepartmentName THEN @row_number+1 ELSE 1 END AS row_number 
    FROM
    Company
    LEFT JOIN People USING (CompanyID)
    LEFT JOIN Departments
    ON Departments.DepartmentID = Company.DepartmentID
    ORDER BY
    Departments.DepartmentID ASC,
    People.LastName ASC,
    People.FirstName ASC;
    )a
```

Comment: I don't think there's an over(partion) in mysql

Comment: It returns sample HTML code in the HTML alias column for every entry. It does not return it only when the employee is the first record returned with their department

Comment: can you add sample data for this. @sjw0525